# Jordan normal form when no eigenvalues

Tags: jordan-normal-form

Is there a Jordan normal form, when the matrix has no eigenvalues at all (over a certain field)?
For example if the characteristic polynomial is like $h(x)=(x^2 + x + 1)^2$ over the reals.
And if yes, how to calculate it?

Comment: Here are two options: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form#A_rational_normal_form_generalizing_the_Jordan_normal_form

Comment: Note that by default, "Jordan form" really only applies to algebraically closed field.

Comment: Note that for a matrix over the reals with the characteristic polynomial $h(x) = (x^2 + x + 1)^2$, there are two possible Jordan forms (whether you define the Jordan form to be block triangular with real entries or triangular with complex entries). One example for each equivalence class:
$$
A = \left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}
0&-1&1&0\\1&-1&0&1\\
\hline
0&0&0&-1\\0&0&1&-1
\end{array}
\right], \quad
B = \left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}
0&-1&0&0\\1&-1&0&0\\
\hline
0&0&0&-1\\0&0&1&-1
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Comment: Many thanks for the comments and hints. A guide to dive deeper.. Thank you